# Integer solutions to $x^3+y^3+z^3=29$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

What are all the triples $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb Z^3$ with
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=29, x \geq y \geq z$$
?
We find immediately $(3,1,1)$, but are there other? According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/can-you-give-an-example-of-a-complex-math-problem-that-is-easy-to-solve/88776#88776) question, it could be a difficult problem.
There might be useful references treating of this equation.

Thank you!

Comment: Are these numbers assumed to be positive?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : for me (and for almost all people, I guess) $\Bbb Z$ includes negative numbers.

Comment: Ok that is clear to me!

Comment: I'm almost certain you can generate more solutions if you find one

Comment: A second solution is $(4,-2,-3)$, a third $(18,13,-20)$, $(235,-69,-233)$ and so on...

Comment: From what I've seen this is normally called the "sum of three cubes" problem which is a difficult problem. Only $x^3+y^3+z^3=k^3,2k^3$ have parameterized solutions (hence infinite solutions) I think. For the rest it is not known whether is solution set is finite.

The latest paper I have seen comes from the Elliptic curve technique [Newer sum of three cubes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07746.pdf).  

Another older reference would be [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02168-6/S0025-5718-08-02168-6.pdf).

Comment: In addition to the 3 solutions given by @RaymondManzoni, there are $-7584, 7552, 1765$; $-11195, 11190, 1234$; $22734, -20075, -15410$; $ 104860, -100464, -51803$; $-146415, 144115, 52609$; $386839, -379133 -150237,\dots$.