# Laurent Series and finding values of the specified sum.

Tags: complex-analysis

Comparing the coefficients in the Laurent developments of $cot(\pi z)$ and its expression as a sum of partial fractions, find the values of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{1}{n^{4}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{1}{n^{6}}$. I am struggling with this problem. I do not know where to start. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: see [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115981/computing-zeta6/116100#116100)

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't quite follow the thread. Which part am I supposed to be following?

Answer (score 2):

Computing the Fourier series of $\cos(zx)$ for $-\pi \le x \le \pi$ returns :

$$
\cos(zx)=\frac{2z\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\left[\frac1{2z^2}+\frac{\cos(1x)}{1^2-z^2}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2^2-z^2}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{3^2-z^2}-\cdots\right]
$$
(details for the Fourier computation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495))

applying this to $x=\pi$ gives :
$$
\cot(\pi z)=\frac1{\pi}\left[\frac1{z}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2z}{k^2-z^2}\right]
$$
that we may rewrite as :
$$
\pi z\cot(\pi z)=1-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^2}{k^2-z^2}
$$
expand $\frac{z^2}{k^2-z^2}$ in Taylor series (for $z < k$) :
$\displaystyle \frac{z^2}{k^2-z^2}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2i}}{k^{2i}}$ so that :

$$
\pi z\cot(\pi z)=1-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2i}}{k^{2i}}=1-2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^{2i}}\right)z^{2i}
$$
$$
\frac{\pi z}2 \cot(\pi z)= \frac 12-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2i)z^{2i}$$

At this point you'll just have to expand $\frac{\pi z}2 \cot(\pi z)$ in powers of $z$ and identify the coefficients of both expansions (for the expansion of $\cot(x)$ search 'cotangent' at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) or deduce it from $\cot(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)$ or from $\cot'(x)=-1-\cot(x)^2$).

(this was more or less my answer combined with the start of the answer of robjohn in the other thread).