# What function do I pick for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/n^6)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computing $\zeta(6)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^6}$ with Fourier series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115981/computing-zeta6-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k6-with-fourier-series)

What function do I pick for the summation from 
$$\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6} \ ?$$
using Parseval's identity

Comment: i dont know what that is?

Comment: The [Riemann Zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\zeta(s)=\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-s}$ generalizes your sum from reciprocal powers of $6$ to (almost) any (complex) exponent $s$ (the real part of $s$ must be greater than one for the series to converge). It is an extensively and actively studied function, quite mysterious and beloved by mathematicians.

Comment: @bgins The somewhat beautiful thing with Parseval here is that it gives an easy way to actually calculate $\zeta(2n)$ $n\ge1$! Other values are much harder: (1) [Apéry]:(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) proved $\zeta(3)$ is irrational in 1979. (2) [Zudilin]:(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadim_Zudilin) proved that $\zeta(5),\,\zeta(7),\,\zeta(9),\,\zeta(11)$ is irrational in 2001.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. In Parseval's formula you will square the Fourier coefficients $c_n$.
2. Can you prove for a generic function $f$ that 
   $$c_n(f)= j_n+\frac{t}{n}c_n(df/dx)$$
   for suitable numbers $j_n$ and $t$.

2'. Can you prove for a generic function $f$ that 
$$c_n(f)= j_n+\frac{k_n}{n}+\frac{t}{n^2}c_n(d^2f/dx^2)$$
for suitable numbers $j_n,\,k_n$ and $t$.

2''. Can you prove for a generic function $f$ that 
$$c_n(f)= j_n+\frac{k_n}{n}+\frac{l_n}{n^2}+\frac{t}{n^3}c_n(d^3f/dx^3)$$
for suitable numbers $j_n,\,k_n,\,l_n$ and $t$.

I hope you see the picture.