# Can someone explain this integration trick for log-sine integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was working on this rather challenging log-sine integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^{2}\ln^{2}\left(2\sin\left(x \over 2\right)\right)\,{\rm d}x = {13\pi^{5} \over 45}
$$

The upper limit is a waiver from the norm of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Anyway, when integrating log-sin integrals one can often times use the famous identity

$$\displaystyle -\ln(2\sin(x/2))=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}$$

by switching sum and integral, integrating, then evaluating the sums. However, this is only valid when $x\neq \pm \pi,\pm2\pi,\ldots$. So, just for the heck of it, I decided to do something I thought would not be viable but have done it anyway. I integrated $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x^{2}\cos^{2}(kx)}{k^{2}},$$ evaluated the resulting sums and arrived at $\displaystyle \frac{41{\pi}^{5}}{180}$.

Now, take the integral $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}x^{2}\ln^{2}(2\cos(x/2))dx=\frac{11{\pi}^{5}}{180}.$$ This one can be done by using Cauchy's cosine formula, differentiating, and so on. Anyway, note that when I add the two results, the correct result for the integral at hand is obtained.

$$\displaystyle \frac{41{\pi}^{5}}{180}+\frac{11{\pi}^{5}}{180}=\frac{13{\pi}^{5}}{45}.$$

By quandary/query is why does this happen to work?. A fluke? Does that cosine sum represent something that when evaluated and added to the above log-cos integral happens to be equivalent to the log-sine integral in question?.

See what I am trying to explain?. I done something I knew I was not supposed to, but it happened to work out. If viable, what would $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{x^{2}\cos^{2}(kx)}{k^{2}}$ represent such that when it is added to $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}x^{2}\ln^{2}(2\cos(x/2))dx=\frac{11{\pi}^{5}}{180}$ equals $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}x^{2}\ln^{2}(2\sin(x/2))dx=\frac{13{\pi}^{5}}{45}$.

I knew I could not just square the cosine and multiply by $x^2$. But,sometimes it can be done due to Parseval, i.e., $\displaystyle \ln^{2}(2\sin(x/2))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)\cos(kx)}{nk}$. Then, because $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)\cos(kx)dx=0, \;\ n\neq k$, one can integrate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^{2}(kx)}{k^{2}}$, then sum.

This works for $2\pi$ as well, but that $x^2$ term tends to throw a wrench in things But I do not think I can do this in my case because of the $x^2$ term.  Or can I?. I was surprised when I saw this. I thought perhaps I stumbled onto a cool way to evaluate this, but I am not entirely sure what I have.

Or, if anyone has their own clever method?.

EDIT:  I managed to evaluate this integral by considering the identity

$$\ln\left(2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=\ln(1-e^{ix})+\frac{i}{2}(\pi -x)$$

Comment: The problem with the identity $\displaystyle -\ln(2\sin(x/2))=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}$ for $x=n\pi$ arises only when $(4m-2)\pi\le n\le 4m\pi,$ where $m\in \Bbb Z$. So the values $x=\pm\pi,\pm 5\pi, \dots$ are OK. Note that $0$ is in the list of problematic values, too.

Comment: Looks like a fluke to me.

Comment: Thanks joriki. I had a feeling it may be, but I wanted to see what you all thought.

Comment: John Benton, slight correction.  The "good" negative multiples of pi are -3*pi, -7*pi, etc, i.e. whenever sin (x/2) is +1.

Comment: It ought not to cause a great deal of trouble that the range of integration spans a value at which the expansion is not valid. It's only _not valid_ by reason of the sine going to zero & therefore the logarithm going to ∞. functions that go to ∞ at the end of some region are quite routinely integrated over that region & found to have finite (though strictly speaking _improper_) integrals. If the ∞ is in the midst of the region, then it's just two such integrals juxtaposed. If you take the usual precautions for evaluating such integrals, then what you are doing is not extraordinary.

Comment: Note sure if this will help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogSineFunction.html?fbclid=IwAR3nHx8YFTIrUfiUdfJktcE7zuCsE169V5sC9XPMbrjgUQXgtd4PfVKoRtw

Comment: If this question still in action?

Answer (score 8):

**Preliminaries**

Looking at the real part of $\log\left(1-e^{ix}\right)$, we get
$$
\log\left(2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}\tag1
$$
Integrating by parts twice, we get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x=\left\{\begin{array}{}\frac{8\pi^3}3&\text{if }k=0\\\frac{4\pi}{k^2}&\text{if }k\ne0\end{array}\right.\tag2
$$

In the derivations below, we use the values of $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(4)$ computed at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116212).

Start to evaluate one sum, then get another:
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00}{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+j)^2kj}}
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{kj}-\frac1{k(k+j)}\right)\left(\frac1{kj}-\frac1{j(k+j)}\right)\tag{3a}\\[3pt]
&=\color{#00F}{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\frac1{j^2}}-2\color{#090}{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k+j)j}}+\color{#C00}{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+j)^2kj}}\tag{3b}\\
\color{#090}{\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k+j)j}}
&=\frac12\color{#00F}{\zeta(2)^2}\tag{3c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\pi^4}{72}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: $\frac1{kj}-\frac1{k(k+j)}=\frac1{j(j+k)}$ and $\frac1{kj}-\frac1{j(k+j)}=\frac1{k(j+k)}$
$\text{(3b)}$: expand the products and separate the sums
$\phantom{\text{(3b):}}$ note that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k+j)j}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+j)j^2}$
$\text{(3c)}$: cancel the red sums, move the green sum to the left side, and divide by $2$
$\text{(3d)}$: simplify

Evaluate the sum we started before (using the other sum we got before):
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+j)^2kj}
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k-j)j}\tag{4a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{k^2(k-j)j}\tag{4b}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{k^3}\left(\frac1{k-j}+\frac1j\right)\tag{4c}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_k}{k^3}-\frac1{k^4}\right)\tag{4d}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{k^3}\left(\frac1j-\frac1{j+k}\right)-2\zeta(4)\tag{4e}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k+j)j}-2\zeta(4)\tag{4f}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{36}-\frac{\pi^4}{45}\tag{4g}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi^4}{180}\tag{4h}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k-j$
$\text{(4b)}$: swap order of summation
$\phantom{\text{(4b):}}$ (we include $k=1$ since the inner sum is then $0$)
$\text{(4c)}$: partial fractions
$\text{(4d)}$: $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{k-j}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1j=H_k-\frac1k$
$\text{(4e)}$: $H_k=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\left(\frac1j-\frac1{j+k}\right)$
$\text{(4f)}$: simplify the summand
$\text{(4g)}$: apply $(3)$
$\text{(4h)}$: simplify

---

**Putting The Preliminaries To Work**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\log\!\left(2\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}\frac{\cos(jx)}{j}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5a}\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\color{#C00}{\cos((k+j)x)}+\color{#090}{\cos((k-j)x)}}{2kj}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5b}\\
&=\color{#C00}{2\pi\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+j)^2kj}}+\color{#090}{4\pi\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\frac1{(k-j)^2kj}+\frac{4\pi^3}3\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}}\tag{5c}\\
&=2\pi\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+j)^2kj}+4\pi\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2(k+j)j}+\frac{4\pi^3}3\zeta(2)\tag{5d}\\
&=\frac{\pi^5}{90}+\frac{\pi^5}{18}+\frac{2\pi^5}9\tag{5e}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{13\pi^5}{45}\tag{5f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(5b)}$: $\cos(a)\cos(b)=\frac{\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)}2$
$\text{(5c)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(5d)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k+j$ in the middle sum
$\text{(5e)}$: apply $(3)$ and $(4)$
$\text{(5f)}$: simplify