# Check the convergence of the series of matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ( 1/ k^2 )  A ^k  $$   where

A =\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Your first equation is weird, did you mean $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}A^k$? Also, please let us know what have you tried and where you are stuck at.

Comment: ok iñm writting all i did

Comment: $k$ should run from $1$ to infinity, not $0$ to infinity.

Comment: I do not how i can conclude that converge or diverge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

1. Let $J=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$. Then $A=-I+J$. Since $J^2=0$, in the binomial expansion of $A^k = (-I+J)^k$, only two terms remain.
2. The value of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}$ is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430973/what-is-the-value-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1nn2).
3. The value of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ is [also known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Provided Lord Soth's interpretation of your question (cf. comment above) is correct, here's an approach which'll help you get what you want:

- Show (by induction, or any means) that $A^k$ has a "nice" expression, of the form
  $$
  A^k = (-1)^k\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \varphi(k) \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
  $$ for some very convenient function $\varphi$;
- Show that $\frac{(-1)^k\varphi(k)}{k^2}$ is a convergent or divergent series. Conclude about the series $\frac{A^k}{k^2}$ (convergence? If so, type of convergence?).

Comment: I prove that  A^n = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}(-1)^n & n(-1)^(n+1) \\ 0 & (-1)^n \end{bmatrix} and then

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/ n^2 = ( 1/ n^2 )  A ^n$$ = $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} $$  \begin{bmatrix}(-1)^n / n^2 & (-1)^(n+1)/n \\ 0 & (-1)^n / n^2 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: I can't read or understand what you typed... I think your expression for $A^n$ is correct, but I cannot be sure unless you correct/fix the $\LaTeX$ code.

Comment: I prove that  $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  ( 1/ n^2 )  A ^n =$$  \begin{bmatrix}(-1)^n / n^2 & (-1)^{(n+1)}/n \\ 0 & (-1)^n / n^2 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: now i do not how conclude that converge or diverge?

Comment: OK. Now, you can conclude (the matrix series converges if it converges coefficient-wise; it converges normally if the series of the norms converges).
(Check what it means for a series of  matrix to converge.)

Comment: Ok you said that i need to compute the norm of \begin{bmatrix}(-1)^n / n^2 & (-1)^{(n+1)}/n \\ 0 & (-1)^n / n^2 \end{bmatrix} then the $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} $$  \begin{bmatrix}(-1)^n / n^2 & (-1)^{(n+1)}/n \\ 0 & (-1)^n / n^2 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: will converge or diverge depending the norm?

Comment: i can not conclude that...

Comment: All I'm saying is that if the norm of $A^n/n^2$ ends up defining a converging series, then $A^n/n^2$ is a series which converges normally. That's the definition. And if each of the four coefficients of $A^n/n^2$ defines a converging series, then $A^n/n^2$ itself is a converging series (at least for the weakest type of convergence).

Comment: yea you are right but i can prove only compute the series of each aij but thanks!

Comment: Take any norm you want (the sup of entries, for instance): it converges for one norm iff it converges for all norms. This is true because it's a space with finite dimension.