# Solve the limit: $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{k}} .$

Tags: integration, limits

> Solve the following limit:
>   $$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{k}} .$$

Here is what I do:

Take the logarithm:
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log \prod\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{k}}&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log (1+\frac{k}{n})}{\frac{k}{n}}\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log (1+x)}{x}dx
\end{align}

Then I am stuck. How to integrate $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log (1+x)}{x}dx $?

The question is from: (8) of https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/files/week4.pdf

Edit: Different approaches are very welcome! The hint says 'estimate from above and below'. Maybe someone can provide a solution without integration?

Comment: Do you know what polylogarithms are? If so, you'd find that the integral is equal to $\operatorname{Li}_2(0)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

Comment: I'm not seeing obvious upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative we have

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log \prod\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}\left( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^{\frac{1}{k}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log (1+\frac{k}{n})}{k}$$

and for a fixed $k$

$$\frac{\log (1+\frac{k}{n})}{k}=\frac1k\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}(k/n)^j}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{jn^j}k^{j-1}$$

and therefore by [**Faulhaber's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log (1+\frac{k}{n})}{k}
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left[\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{jn^j}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{j-1}\right]
\to\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{{j^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Refer also to the related

- [What is the value of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430973/505767)

Answer (score 1):

Find the Talyor series  for $\log(1+x)/x$ and integrate termwise, and get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}=\zeta(2)-\frac{2}{4}\zeta(2)=\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$