# Source for closed form of sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\zeta(2+2n)x^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, riemann-zeta

I recently came across the following summation:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\zeta(2+2n)x^{2n}=\frac{1-\pi x\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2},$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. Wolfram MathWorld cites Bailey et. al. 2006, but I can't seem to find that source in the references. Does anybody know where this reference is located (or any other place to find the evaluation of this sum)?

Comment: You can find that source [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/D-Luke-2/publication/228547058_Experimental_mathematics_in_action/links/0912f50b6ea9266cfd000000/Experimental-mathematics-in-action.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891312/a-cotangent-series-related-to-the-zeta-function) MSE question the OP derives to a very similar expression
$$x\cot x = 1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2n)\frac{x^{2n}}{\pi^{2n}}.$$
To get to this result he starts with the Weiertrass product of the sine.
So, how can we get from this expression to yours? First of all we can bring the $1$ as well as the $-2$ to the left hand side.
$$\frac{1-x\cot x}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2n)\frac{x^{2n}}{\pi^{2n}}.$$
Now substitute $x\to\pi x$. This yields
$$\frac{1-\pi x\cot \pi x}{2} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2n)\frac{(\pi x)^{2n}}{\pi^{2n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2n)x^{2n}.$$

Start from $n=0$ instead from $n=1$, by writing every $n$ as $n+1$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2n)x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\zeta(2(n+1))x^{2(n+1)} =x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\zeta(2n+2)x^{2n}.$$
Remember what the sum was equal to and divide both sides by $x^2$
$${\frac{1-\pi x\cot \pi x}{2x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\zeta(2n+2)x^{2n}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the very nice derivation. In case you're interested you can also use this formula to get a closed form for the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty[n^{2k}(x-n^2)]^{-1}$ for any natural number $k$ (which is the original application I had in mind).

Comment: Interesting. I would like to see your proof. Do you have it as a latex document? If yes, could you post the link in here?

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.overleaf.com/6415664718fwggfshpsdsr. I'm not an expert in complex analysis but I'm pretty sure this is correct (Mathematica confirms it, at least for given values of $k$).