# How to prove that $\frac{\zeta(2) }{2}+\frac{\zeta (4)}{2^3}+\frac{\zeta (6)}{2^5}+\frac{\zeta (8)}{2^7}+\cdots=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, zeta-functions

How can one prove this identity?

> $$\frac{\zeta(2) }{2}+\frac{\zeta (4)}{2^3}+\frac{\zeta (6)}{2^5}+\frac{\zeta (8)}{2^7}+\cdots=1$$

---

There is a formula for [$\zeta$ values at even integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers), but it involves Bernoulli numbers; simply plugging it in does not appear to be an efficient approach.

Comment: I think this is a normal question. I don't know why "on hold"?

Comment: There is a recursive formula for $\zeta(2n)$ derived in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/116212). However, in that answer it is shown that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\zeta(2k)x^{2k}=\frac12(1-\pi x\cot(\pi x))$$ With $x=\frac12$, this immediately gives $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\zeta(2k)\left(\frac12\right)^{2k-1} =1-\frac\pi2\cot\left(\frac\pi2\right)=1$$ This is what is used in Random Variable's answer.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Since

$$\zeta(2n) = \frac{1}{(2n-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx $$

we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2^{2n-1}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh(x/2)}{e^x-1}\,dx =\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x/2}\,dx = \color{red}{1}.$$

Comment: @mathworker21: I can mention that the dominated (or just monotone) convergence theorem clearly applies here.

Answer (score 145):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2^{2n-1}}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac2{k^{2n}2^{2n}}\tag{1}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(4k^2)^n}\tag{2}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{4k^2-1}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)\tag{4}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1):}$ expand $\zeta(2n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{2n}}$
$\text{(2):}$ change the order of summation
$\phantom{\text{(2):}}$ allowed because the terms are all positive
$\text{(3):}$ sum of a geometric series
$\text{(4):}$ partial fractions
$\text{(5):}$ telescoping sum

Comment: @robjohn, in  $(3)$ the numerator should have a $4k^2$. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4k^2)^n} = \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{4k^2}} = \frac{4k^2}{4k^2 - 1}$$

Comment: @Amad27: Notice that the sum starts from $n=1$. This means that the sum is $\dfrac{\frac1{4k^2}}{1-\frac1{4k^2}}$.

Comment: Ah! I couldn't catch the index! Sorry robjohn!

Comment: This one appears to be simplest possible answer. +1 It is as if you see the result in question at the level of $1 + r + r^{2} + \cdots = 1/(1 - r)$.

Comment: Plain and simple - as always @robjohn :)

Comment: +1 Elegant and nice answer.

Comment: If there is a step that is unclear, it might be useful to mention that rather than/along with downvoting.

Comment: I have expanded the explanation of step $(2)$ in case that was the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 48):

The [Laurent expansion of $\cot (z)$ at the origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions) in terms of the Riemann zeta function is $$ \cot (z) = \frac{1}{z} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta(2k) \frac{z^{2k-1}}{\pi^{2k}} \ , \ 0 < |z| < \pi. $$

Letting $ \displaystyle z= \frac{\pi}{2}$, $$\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \frac{2}{\pi} - \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2k)}{2^{2k-1}}.$$

But $\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right)=0$.

Therefore,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2k)}{2^{2k-1}} = 1.$$

Comment: +1. Nice. I was doing something like that with identities [$\color{black}{\bf 6.3.14}$ and $\color{black}{\bf 6.3.15}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) but I left because it was  cumbersome.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks. This actually wasn't my first approach.

Comment: (+1) Beautiful approach! This relation is also proven in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/116212).

Answer (score 15):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace{#1}\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack{#1}\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert{#1}\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\zeta\pars{2n} \over 2^{2n - 1}}} =
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\zeta\pars{n} \over 2^{n - 1}} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\zeta\pars{2n + 1} \over 2^{2n}}
\\[3mm] = &\
-\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\zeta\pars{n}\pars{-\,\half}^{n - 1} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta\pars{2n + 1} - 1}\pars{\half}^{2n}\ -\
\underbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{2n}}_{\ds{1 \over 3}}
\\ = &\
-\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 + z} + \gamma}_{\ z\ =\ -1/2}
\\[3mm] & - \bracks{%
{1 \over 2z} - \half\,\pi\cot\pars{\pi z} - {1 \over 1 - z^{2}} + 1 - \gamma - \Psi\pars{1 + z}}_{\ z\ =\ 1/2} - {1 \over 3}
\\[8mm] = &\
-\Psi\pars{\half} - {2 \over 3}\ +\ 
\underbrace{\Psi\pars{3 \over 2}}_{\ds{\Psi\pars{1/2} + 1/\pars{1/2}}} -
{1 \over 3} = \color{#f00}{1}
\end{align}

> $\Psi$ and $\gamma$ are the *Digamma function* and the *Euler-Mascheroni constant*, respectively. We used the *Digamma Recurrence Formula* $\ds{\Psi\pars{z + 1} = \Psi\pars{z} + 1/z}$ and the identities $\mathbf{6.3.14}$ and $\mathbf{6.3.15}$ [in this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).