# What is known about rational sums of powers of zeta values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

A fair bit is known about rational zeta [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series). This includes identities such as $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} [\zeta(n) -1] = 1 $$ and $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} [\zeta(n)-1] = 1-\gamma .$$
Many more identities can be found in articles by e.g. [Borwein](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/borwein1.pdf) and Adamchik & Srivastava ([here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/sums/zeta.pdf)).

So far, I have not been able to find identities for series involving powers of zeta values. For instance, I wonder what the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}[\zeta(n)-1]^{p} $$ amounts to, for some positive integer $p$. Are there any results on these and related types of sums?

Comment: @MarcoCantarini This is one of the types of generalizations I'm thinking about

Comment: I actually asked an analogous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3712044/595055) concerning $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( (\zeta(n))^k -1\right)$. Expanding your summand via the binomial theorem, it would be a linear combination of $(\zeta(n))^p -1, (\zeta(n))^{p-1} -1, ..., -1$.

Comment: Nice problem.  Work on $p=2$ to start with.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you. I've tried, but to no avail so far. If you have solution, I'd be very interested in reading about it.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Ah, it seems we have similar interests. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @GEdgar do you happen to know whether any articles have been written on rational sums of powers of zeta values?

Comment: A copy of this question is montioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373231/51189)