# What is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{d(n)}{n(n-1)} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

While trying to evaluate a multiple rational zeta [series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373231/what-is-known-about-sums-of-the-form-sum-n-2-infty-zetan-1p), the following sum came up:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{d(n)}{n(n-1)} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \Big{(} \frac{d(n)}{n-1} - \frac{d(n)}{n} \Big{)}. \qquad \qquad \qquad (*) $$
This equality can be obtained by partial fraction decomposition.

I tried evaluating the right-hand side by considering the partial asymptotic sum $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{d(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{2}(\log(x))^{2}+2\gamma\log (x)+\gamma^{2}-2\gamma_{1}+O\left(x^{-1/2}\right),$$ and see if there's an [analogue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53283/max-muller) for $\sum d(n)/(n-1) $. So far, I haven't succeeded.

Another approach to evaluate $(*)$ is to consider the generating [functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14003576)

\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} d(n)q^{n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^{n}}{1-q^{n}} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+q^{n}}{1-q^{n}} q^{n^{2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{(q;q)_{\infty}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n q^{\binom{n+1}{2}}}{(q;q)_{n}} \quad,
\end{align}

where $(a;q)_{n} := (1-a)(1-aq)(1-aq^{2})\dots(1-aq^{n-1})$ is the $q$-shifted [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) .

One could proceed by dividing either of these expressions by $q^{2}$, integrate twice, and then set $q=1$. However, integrating either of these summands seems like quite a formidable task.

Finally, note that a related sum can be evaluated: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d(n)}{n^{2}} = \zeta^{2}(2) = \frac{\pi^{4}}{36} $$ (see e.g. equation (19) [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)).

**Question**: can $(*)$ be evaluated? If there aren't any results on this, I'm also interested in other sums that are related to this one of which the exact evaluation is known.

Comment: Have you tried obtaining the asymptotics of $$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{{d(n)}}{{n - 1}}} 
$$ using summation by parts?

Comment: @Gary no, not yet

Comment: Equals $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\big(\zeta^2(n)-1\big)$. (Just found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3712044).)

Comment: @metamorphy Ah yes, but it equals that minus $d'(1)$, no? As a limit is involved as well

Comment: What is "$d'(1)$"? Anyway, what I mean is $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{d(n)}{n(n-1)}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty d(n)\sum_{k=2}^\infty n^{-k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{d(n)}{n^k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\big(\zeta^2(k)-1\big).$$