# Wolfram Alpha can't find an explicit form (or even an explicit form of an approximation of) this innocuous series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory

I suppose my question could be restated as "why?" to the above statement. 
I'll rephrase my question if this breaks any rules asking it this way, but the expression is simply:

$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{m^{2n}(m^2-1)} = ??$$

with the partial sum being:
$$\sum_{m=2}^a \frac{1}{m^{2n}(m^2-1)} = ??$$

$m, n \in \mathbb N$

Are the above two somehow more insidious than they look?

Comment: Since we don’t even know whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^{-5}}$ is irrational, it is not as surprising as you could think.

Comment: Given a nonnegative integer $n$  we should have an explicit result. If we do not give $n$, I guess that Mathematica considers $n$ as a complex argument.

Comment: @Mindlack The proposed series can be evaluated for any non-negative integer $n$.

Comment: Mathematica is too smart for its own good, WA even more so ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your series is innocuous **if $n$ is a non-negative integer**: by partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{m^{2n}(m^2-1)}=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{m^{2k}}+\frac{1/2}{m-1}-\frac{1/2}{m+1}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{2n}(m^2-1)} = 
-\sum_{k=1}^n\zeta(2k)+n+\frac{3}{4}$$
where $\zeta(2k)=\frac{|B_{2k}|(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}$ (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers)).

However, I guess that [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(1%2Fm%5E(2*n)%2F(m%5E2-1),m%3D2..infinity);) considers $n$ as a complex argument (not as a non negative integer). On the other hand, given an explicit non negative integer $n$, wolframalpha will give you the result.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac1{m^{2n}(m^2-1)}
&=\sum_{m=2}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty m^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\sum_{m=2}^\infty m^{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty(\zeta(2k)-1)\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac34-\sum_{k=1}^n(\zeta(2k)-1)}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
since
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\zeta(2k)-1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^{2k}}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{2k}}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^2-1}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac34\tag2
\end{align}
$$
In $(1)$, $\zeta(2k)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^{2k}$, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116212).

Here are the first several sums:
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
n&\frac34-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\zeta(2k)-1)\\\hline
1&\frac74-\frac{\pi^2}6\\
2&\frac{11}4-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi^4}{90}\\
3&\frac{15}4-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^6}{945}\\
4&\frac{19}4-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^6}{945}-\frac{\pi^8}{9450}\\
5&\frac{23}4-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^6}{945}-\frac{\pi^8}{9450}-\frac{\pi^{10}}{93555}\\
6&\frac{27}4-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^6}{945}-\frac{\pi^8}{9450}-\frac{\pi^{10}}{93555}-\frac{691\pi^{12}}{638512875}
\end{array}\tag3
$$

Comment: I don't see where the closed form is expressed, it seems like replacing a series with an even harder to calculate series to me!

Comment: It is replacing an infinite series with a finite sum (note that the sum in $(1)$ is finite). $\zeta(2k)$ has a closed form as a rational multiple of $\pi^{2k}$ as shown in the cited answer. Both Robert Z and I got the same finite sum. I doubt there is a simpler form, though there could be.