# What's the generalization for $\zeta(2n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, riemann-zeta

We know that

$$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\tag1$$

$$\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}
\tag2$$

$$\zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{945}\tag3$$
$$.$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

My question is there a generalization for $\zeta(2n)$ in term of $\pi^{2n}$?

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: It involves Bernoulli numbers

Comment: The main point is that $$f(z)=\frac1{e^z-1}-\frac1z = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac1{z+2i\pi n}+ \frac1{z-2i\pi n}$$ (you can look at the Fourier series of the periodic function $\sum_n \frac1{x+iy+2\pi n}$) differentiating we obtain $2 (2i\pi)^{-2k}\zeta(2k)=\frac{f^{(2k-1)}(0)}{(2k-1)!}= \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$

Comment: @reuns thank you. why dont you post your comment as an answer? Its a good one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116212), it is shown that
$$
\zeta(2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\pi^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\!\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\pi^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\zeta(2n-2k)
$$
which can be used recursively to compute $\zeta(2n)$ for all $n\ge1$.

This can easily be modified to
$$
\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(2n+1)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\!\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k+1)!}\frac{\zeta(2n-2k)}{\pi^{2n-2k}}
$$
which shows that $\frac{\zeta(2n)}{\pi^{2n}}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks Rob that's really impressive (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [generalization](https://problemasteoremas.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/determinacao-dos-valores-da-funcao-zeta-nos-pares-atraves-de-uma-serie-de-fourier/) by *@Américo Tavares* where you can find the evaluation of $\zeta(2p)$ using the Fourier series for $x^{2p}$,

$$x^{2p}=\frac{\pi ^{2p}}{2p+1}+\frac{2}{\pi }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left( \cos nx\cdot I_{2p}\right)$$

where

$$I_{2p}=\int_{0}^{\pi }x^{2p}\cos nx\;\mathrm{d}x$$

In the link, you can find the proof of $\zeta(2)$, $\zeta(4)$ and $\zeta(6)$.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function) tells us that $$
\zeta (2n)=(-1)^{{n+1}}{\frac  {B_{{2n}}(2\pi )^{{2n}}}{2(2n)!}}
$$
where $B_n$ is the $n$-th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), a rational number.

Comment: the link you provided is already mentioned in the first comment. thanks tho

Comment: @AliShather, yes, hence the community wiki tag. Anyway, it's better to have answers than comments.

Comment: I agree with you. thanks again