# $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Riemann zeta function at odd positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/riemann-zeta-function-at-odd-positive-integers)

We know that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and also for every even number it's known, but it's still unknown what the exact value of $\zeta(3)$ is. How is it possible that $\zeta(2)$ has been calculated circa 250 years ago, but $\zeta(3)$ is stil not calculated exactly? Why is the difference in difficulty so big?

Comment: Actually it can be calculated fairly easily using fourier series techniques. The problem is expressing it with known mathematical constants like e and $\pi$. Thats where the difficulty is.