# Closed form for $\zeta(3)$

Tags: zeta-functions

I was reading about [Euler's approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler%27s_approach) for the closed form of $\zeta(2)$. On the same lines, if we instead consider the factorization

$x(1-\frac{x}{\pi})(1+\frac{x}{\pi})(1-\frac{x}{2\sqrt2\pi})(1+\frac{x}{2\sqrt2\pi})(1-\frac{x}{3\sqrt3\pi})(1+\frac{x}{3\sqrt3\pi})(1-\frac{x}{4\sqrt4\pi})(1+\frac{x}{4\sqrt4\pi})...$,

i.e.,

$x(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{2^3\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{3^3\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{4^3\pi^2})...$,

will it just be a matter of finding a trigonometric function representation of this polynomial ($\sin(x)$ in case of Euler's method), that when expanded as a Taylor series, and its co-efficients compared with the polynomial, that we shall be able to find a closed form for

$1 + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{4^3} + ...$ ?

Further, if it can be proved that no trigonometric function can express the above polynomial, will that mean that no closed form for $\zeta(3)$ exists?

Please forgive my limited knowledge on this topic, lack of research, and only quoting Wikipedia.

Comment: What do you mean by a "closed form"?

Comment: By [Apéry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_theorem) we know that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational. A proof is shown [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202159).

There are no known techniques for finding a closed form of $\zeta(3)$ or $\zeta(k)$ where $k$ is an odd integer. This is an open problem and is an active area of research.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/riemann-zeta-function-at-odd-positive-integers) with links to similar questions on Math SE.

Comment: @Axion004 There is a closed form. $\zeta(3)=\operatorname{Li}_3(1)$.

Comment: The word *closed form* is not a mathematically well defined terminology, just as e.g. *elementary proof*.

Comment: @WhatsUp one acceptable definition is in terms of finite operations of arithmetic and exponential/logarithm of the natural numbers, similar in spirit to closed form of integrals in liouvilles theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this closed form over internet a long time ago, wolframalpha confirm that it is correct, but I've also a very limited math knowledge, I have no idea if it can be considered as closed form since it involve the third-order derivative of Gamma or polyGamma functions

I think it's coming from Plouffe's inverter

$\zeta(3) = -{1\over2}\biggl(\gamma^3+{1\over2}(\gamma\pi^2)+\Gamma'''(1)\biggl)$

[wolframalpha computation result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1%2F2%28eulerGamma%5E3%20%2B%20%28%28eulerGamma*pi%5E2%29%2F2%29%20%2B%20gamma%27%27%27%281%29%29)

Proposed as alternate form by wolframalpha :

$\zeta(3) = -{{\psi^{(2)}(1)}\over2}$

[wolframalpha computation result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-polygamma%282%2C%201%29%2F2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The idea for your formula is simply to start with this [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) expression : $$\psi(z) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\ln\Gamma(z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$$
so that $\Gamma'(z)=\Gamma(z) \psi(z)$  
and
$\;\displaystyle\Gamma'''(z)=\Gamma(z) \psi(z)^3 + 3\,\Gamma(z) \psi'(z) \psi(z) + \Gamma(z) \psi''(z)$ and conclude using :
$\psi(1)=-\gamma,\;\psi'(1)=\zeta(2),\;\psi''(1)=-2\,\zeta(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer.*

I'm not sure if [Ch'nycos's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4768262/762384) will stay, but to support its claims a bit, by rearranging the Polygamma function's  recurrence relation  we obtain,
$$\frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{\psi^{(2)}(n+1)-\psi^{(2)}(n)}{2}$$
summing over $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\psi^{(2)}(n+1)-\psi^{(2)}(n)=-\frac{\psi^{(2)}(1)}{2}$$
after telescoping the series.